# list of intrinsic constants

Tags: vbscript

Where can I find a complete list of the intrinsic constants in VBScript (like vbCrLf and vbTab)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official and most up-to-date reference is in the MSDN library:

[**Constants (VBScript)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydz4cfk3.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://www.csidata.com/custserv/onlinehelp/vbsdocs/vbscon3.htm) what you need?

Comment: Yes, thanks!  But I don't understand what is meant by "For VBScript, you must explicitly declare these constants in your code."  Is there a code example for how to do that?

Comment: @JoelFan this means you have to declare them on your code before use. Some people usually make an include with this variables to make it reusable. The most common is the ADODB.inc, that you can find on a Google search and beter understand what I'm saing.